# WPF MenuItem Click event called two times instead of one time

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a `Menu` in my XAML that look like this

```xml
<Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="20">
    <MenuItem Width="20" Height="20" x:Name="MenuItem_AddNewQuality">
        <MenuItem.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="MenuItem_AddNewQuality_Click"></EventSetter>
            </Style>
        </MenuItem.Resources>
        <MenuItem.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="icons8-add-50.png"/>
        </MenuItem.Background>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
            <local:DataTemplateSelector_MenuItem_AddNewQuality_SelectType>
                <local:DataTemplateSelector_MenuItem_AddNewQuality_SelectType.DataTemplate_Enabled>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </local:DataTemplateSelector_MenuItem_AddNewQuality_SelectType.DataTemplate_Enabled>
                <local:DataTemplateSelector_MenuItem_AddNewQuality_SelectType.DataTemplate_Disenabled>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" IsEnabled="False"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </local:DataTemplateSelector_MenuItem_AddNewQuality_SelectType.DataTemplate_Disenabled>
            </local:DataTemplateSelector_MenuItem_AddNewQuality_SelectType>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Width="20" Click="Button_RemoveSelectedQuality_Click" IsEnabled="{Binding HasItemSelectedandSelectedItemHasQuality, ElementName=window, Mode=OneWay}" Height="20">
        <MenuItem.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="icons8-delete-bin-50.png"/>
        </MenuItem.Background>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

However the `MenuItem_AddNewQuality_Click()` was executed two times.
Then I tried to remove

```xml
<EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="MenuItem_AddNewQuality_Click"></EventSetter>
```

But this time there are no thing executed.
So can any one please tell me what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set in your event handler, that event was handled, then you will get it called only one time:

```
private void MenuItem_AddNewQuality_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //....
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Another way would be set `Click` event not as implicit style for all nested menu items(this is what you have with double call), but explicitly in `MenuItem`:

```
<MenuItem Width="20" Height="20" x:Name="MenuItem_AddNewQuality" Click="MenuItem_AddNewQuality_Click">
```

Another way is to declare an explicit style and apply it to the `MenuItem`:

```
<Style x:Key="MenItemStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
    <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="MenuItem_AddNewQuality_Click"/>
</Style>
<MenuItem Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MenItemStyle}">
```

Comment: Depending on objectives of the application one or another solution can be taken or considered as work around. If you see all solutions as work around, then feel free to post the right solution.